# Syntax error unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a number guessing game that covers 4 .py files and 1 .txt file. the problem is that on part2 (There are :main.py, part1.py, part2.py and part3.py) I get a syntax error.(Title was just so I was allowed to post the question.)
This is my code.

```
while (gussestaken < guesses):
    try:    
        guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
        gussestaken = (guessestaken + 1)
        if guess > maxnum or guess < 0:
            print('Please, %s, enter a valid choice. Remember the maximum is %d.' % (name, maxnum))
```

I get a Syntax error unexpected EOF while parsing right after the last bracket.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to catch a `ValueError`(when the user inputs a string), try this:

```
while (gussestaken < guesses):
    try:    
        guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
        gussestaken = (guessestaken + 1)
        if guess > maxnum or guess < 0:
            print('Please, %s, enter a valid choice. Remember the maximum is %d.' % (name, maxnum))
    except ValueError:
        print "Opps! You entered a string."
        break
```

Comment: ohh i just relised that i had no except at the end of the try-except block. Thanks.